# Protecting SQL Insert Of CSV File From SQL Injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, csv, pdo

I am converting my code to protect it from SQL Injection.

Currently I have converted most of my code and got it working but I have two queries that I am a little confused about. I am working from the php docs [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Example 4 is the situation I think I need to be using. But I do not understand how this will get the value I need into my prepared statement.

The first statement that I need to change is,

```
require_once('Dbconfig.php');

$limit  = (intval($_GET['limit']) != 0) ? $_GET['limit'] : 5;
$offset = (intval($_GET['offset']) != 0) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM wuno_inventory WHERE 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
try {
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
if (count($results) > 0) {
    foreach ($results as $res) {
        echo '<tr class="invent">';
        echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_product'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_alternates'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_description'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_onhand'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_condition'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
?>
```

And the second statement I need to convert is,

```
<?php
require_once ('Dbconfig.php');

$limit = (intval($_GET['limit']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 5;
$offset = (intval($_GET['offset']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

if(!empty($_POST["itemID"])) {
 $sql=" SELECT * FROM wuno_inventory WHERE wuno_product like '%". $_POST["itemID"] ."%' OR wuno_alternates like '%". $_POST["itemID"] ."%' ORDER BY wuno_product ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset ";
try {
  $stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
if (count($results) > 0) {
  foreach ($results as $res) {
    echo '<tr class="invent">';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_product'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_alternates'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_description'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_onhand'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_condition'] . '</td>';  
    echo '</tr>';   
  }
}
}
?>
```

This is the example I was trying to use,

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name = ?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['name']))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
}
?>
```

I do not understand how and why adding a `?` in the statement works. Is it truly telling me all I need to do is add a `?` where my two column names are? Please show me how to convert these two statement to prepared statements to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Honestly, that is all you need to do. The prepared statement library takes care of making sure the data entered into columns is "safe" thereby preventing SQL Injection. [*"Prepared statements are resilient against SQL injection, because parameter values, which are transmitted later using a different protocol, need not be correctly escaped. If the original statement template is not derived from external input, SQL injection cannot occur."*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

Comment: So it just knows that if a form post to the page whatever the value is will just automatically take the place of the ?

Comment: You're specifying the values from the form in the array that you place in the execute statement. The array should be in the same order that your placeholders (`?`) are in your query.

Comment: Ok thank you, for the sake of being clear so I can finally move on from trying to understand this would you mind answering the question with at least just one of my statements?  I would really appreciate it. I am worried that I am making these work and that in the end I am not for sure preventing sql injection. I am not worried about being hacked I am concerned with doing a professional job and having good habits.

Comment: In the first query you cannot use placeholders in place of the variables but you should take more care with sanitizing user input. The second query is open to sql injection as you directly inject posted variables into your sql with absolutely no saftey checks or cleansing. The power of prepared statements comes from using the placeholders, preparing the statement for execution and substituting the actual variables at runtime.

Comment: In the assignment of `$limit` and `$offset`, I would definitely make that second argument **`intval($_GET(foo))`** rather than just **`$_GET(foo)`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prepared statement library takes care of making sure the data entered into columns is "safe" thereby preventing SQL Injection.

Here is how you would use the placeholder (`?`) in one of your code examples as a prepared statement:

```
if(!empty($_POST["itemID"])) {
 $sql=" SELECT * FROM wuno_inventory WHERE wuno_product like ? OR wuno_alternates like ? ORDER BY wuno_product ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset ";
try {
      $stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute(array('%'.$_POST['itemID'].'%','%'.$_POST['itemID'].'%')); // two placeholders in the query means two items in the array
      $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
       echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Read more on [Demystifying PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

> YOU MUST pass all values to bind in an array to `PDOStatement->execute()` or you have to bind every value with `PDOStatement->bindValue()`, then call `PDOStatement->execute()` with no parameters. Passing an array (empty or not) to `execute()` will replace any previous bindings and can lead to errors, e.g. with MySQL the error "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031" (CR_PARAMS_NOT_BOUND) if you passed an empty array.

Comment: So to make it safe has nothing to do with making prepared in the statement its self like this, $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name = ?");

Comment: The basis of a prepared statement is a query with placeholders. The safety comes when sending the parameters for the placeholders.

Comment: Thank you sir. So in the future make sure I use placeholder in the query. Don't worry about whether the word prepared is used in the statement. It all is based on using place holders in the query?

Comment: Correct. That and then binding the query parameters either in an array or by using one of the bind methods.

Comment: Yes I binded them in my other query. These ones were a little more confusing. Thank you very much.

Comment: Unless the assignment of `$limit` and `$offset` are addressed, the change in this answer only partially addresses SQL Injection vulnerabilities. The second argument should be `intval($_GET(foo)` not just `$_GET(foo)`.

Comment: I was just looking at that. I am super confused on this one.. I wish there was a way to get a better understanding of this based on my exact circumstances. I mean if I am selecting all from the db and basing it off of my variables limit and offset I can just bind them to an array just like the last one?